# Кроссбраузерное выравнивание изображения с помощью Flexbox

Tags: css

Хотел бы узнать, есть кроссбраузерный способ, выравнивания картинки по центру, вертикально и горизонтально, с помощью Flex, например чтобы картинка была 4:3 или 3:4 и всегда по центру, и при этом изображение не растягивалось в обоих случаях. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

не до конца понял что требуется, но сделал выравнивание картинки по центру здесь, поясните, если что не так

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.Aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Aligner-item--fixed {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Aligner">
  <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item--fixed">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/cats/" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пляски с `flex: 1;` и `flex: none;` не нужны. Удалите эти правила вообще.

Comment: В коде много лишних элементов, не относящихся к сути вопроса, это усложняет понимание и вводит в заблуждение.